# Using ggplot to plot occupied parking spaces in a parking lot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’d like to use ggplot to draw a grid plot of the following scenario which I’ve attempted to depict in the picture below... I could use some guidance on how to logically think about the approach.  Thank you for the guidance.

### --

Each aisle in the example picture below has an odd number side—and an even number side

The spaces on the odd-side are listed ascending from 1… K where K is odd

The spaces on the even-side are listed ascending from 2…N where N is even 

This pattern exists for each aisle in the parking lot

If a car is parked in a space—we track that spot in a database.

How can I reproduce a grid-level ggplot to indicate with a symbol on the plot all spaces where a car is parked?

[image: Parking Lot Example]

The listing of occupied spaces would be “fed” into the ggplot logic via a .csv file:  the format of the .csv would look something like this:

A01

A04

A05

A08

A09

A15

A20

A33

B07

B31

B44

C01

C04

C36

...

Image credit: Michael Layefsky, 2010, Google Images

Comment: This sounds like a fun graphics challenge and someone will probably come along and just give you the answer. But you might try telling what you've already tried and why that wasn't sufficient to solve the problem or where you got stuck. If you haven't tried anything yet, I know why it's not working!

Comment: Tip: start by plotting a single rhombus that roughly matches the shape of one parking space. How would you repeat that across a field to produce an outline of blank spaces? Now how would you go and fill some of them in?

Comment: HI arvi1000, I'm not even out of the gate on this one. The idea is stuck in the brain -- and I'm not smart enough (at this point) to manifest the idea into reality with syntax.

Comment: I am not sure why you would use `ggplot` (which is for 2D charts and figures) and not just `grid`, which is what `ggplot` is based on. `grid` is a general graphics package and is quite suitable for such tasks. `ggplot` is not really the right tool here I think (although I don't doubt that you could abuse it and get *something* working).

Comment: agree with @MikeWise.  Can you clarify whether `ggplot` is really a requirement, and if so why?

Comment: Hi Ben, I had read ggplot was more flexible, but seeing the examples below, it was pure luck on my part that I was moving in the direction of ggplot over using grid.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are taking a list of only the occupied spots as input in the form that you showed, and then you want to produce a visualization of occupied spots using `ggplot2`, this approach will work.  First, I process the input, turning it into something that I can give `ggplot` easily.

```
# the provided example data
d <- read.table(text="
A01 
A04 
A05 
A08 
A09 
A15 
A20 
A33 
B07 
B31 
B44 
C01 
C04 
C36", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Split the "spaces" into meaningful coordinates.  I kept the original space names around for later labeling.  What follows is all manipulation used to get the plot set up correctly.

```
cars <- strsplit(d[,1], "(?<=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE) # split the raw data
# turn resulting list into data.frame and give it names
cars <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, cars), c("aisle","spot.num"))
# convert the from factors to numeric, 
# and turn the aisle letter into numeric data for plotting 
# retain the original spot id for labeling the plot 
cars <- with(cars, data.frame(
  spot.num = as.numeric(as.character(spot.num)),
  aisle = aisle, # keep this around for faceting
  aisle.coord = 2 * (utf8ToInt(paste(as.character(aisle), collapse="")) - utf8ToInt("A")),
  spot.id = d[,1]))
```

I multiplied the `aisle` by 2 after converting A to 1, B to 2, and so on, to make a new variable called `aisle.coord`.  The reason for multiplying by 2 is to set up a variable where each aisle can be composed of two lines:

```
# if the spot number is even, increment aisle by 1 (put it on the right).
# This is possible because I multiplied by 2 earlier
cars$aisle.coord[cars$spot.num %% 2 == 0] <- cars$aisle.coord[cars$spot.num %% 2 == 0] + 1 
# We need to adjust the spot numbers to real row numbers
# i.e. A02 is in row 1, not row 2, A10 is in row 5, etc.
cars$spot <- ceiling(cars$spot.num / 2)
```

Now, the plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid) # for unit()

ggplot(cars, aes(x = aisle.coord %% 2, y = spot)) + 
  geom_tile(width = 0.5, height = 0.8) +
  facet_grid(~aisle) + 
  geom_text( aes(x = aisle.coord %% 2, y = spot, label = spot.id), color = "white")
```

That is a bare-bones attempt at the graph.  Lots of room for you to improve and adjust it.  Here is another attempt with a little more effort.  Still, plenty of room for adjustment (e.g. you could adjust the plot so that a the full lot appears, not just the part of the lot up to the maximum spot: B44):

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = aisle.coord %% 2, y = spot)) + 
  geom_tile(width = 0.5, height = 0.8, fill = "orange") +
  facet_grid(~aisle) + 
  geom_text( aes(x = aisle.coord %% 2, y = spot, label = spot.id), color = "white", size = 4) +
  annotate("rect", ymin = 0, ymax = max(cars$spot)+0.5, xmin = 0.3, xmax = 0.7, fill = "grey40") +
  theme(panel.margin.x = unit(0.05, "lines"), 
    plot.background = element_rect("grey40"),
    panel.background = element_rect("grey40"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.5, (max(cars$spot) + 0.5), 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-0.3, 1.3)) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x = 0.5, y = 10, aisle = LETTERS[1:length(unique(cars$aisle))]),
    aes(x = x, y = y, label = aisle), inherit.aes = FALSE, color = "white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

My experience with direct use of `grid` is limited, so I can't say how hard this would be with `grid` functions, but it seems reasonably straightforward in `ggplot2`. Here's a simple example that is (I hope) not too far off from what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Set up grid of space identifiers
df = data.frame(y=1:10, x=rep(c(0:1, 3:4, 6:7), each=10),
                space=paste0(rep(c("A","B","C"), each=20), 
                            rep(c(seq(2,20,2),seq(1,20,2)), 3)), 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Assume we have a vector of occupied spaces
set.seed(194)
occupied = sample(df$space, 30)

# Mark occupied spaces in data frame
df$status = ifelse(df$space %in% occupied, "Occupied", "Available")

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x - 0.5, xend=x + 0.5, y=y, yend=y - 1)) +
  geom_label(aes(label=space, x=x, y=y, fill=status), colour="blue", label.size=0) +
  annotate(geom="segment", x=seq(0.5,6.5,3), xend=seq(0.5,6.5,3), 
           y=rep(0,3), yend=rep(10,3), lty="11") +
  theme_bw(base_size=14) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(hcl(c(105,15),100,65))) +
  #scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA, hcl(15,100,65))) +    # Color only occupied spaces
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="",y="",fill="")
```

[image]